# Set Interrupt Flag (sti) crashes linux kernel

Tags: linux, linux-kernel, interrupt, sti

I wrote a simple character device for testing purposes (Linux).
I have a VM with 2 cores.
CPU0 and CPU1.

I have this code in the character device:

`native_irq_enable();
smp_call_function_single(#Other CPU#,native_irq_enable);`

if I compile the character device without the smp_call everything works OK.
If I call to another function for example: `smp_call_function_single(#Othe CPU#,native_halt())`
, the kernel will not crash. But if I call `smp_call_function_single(#Othe CPU#,native_safe_halt())` the kernel will CRASH because I set the IF (interrupt flag).

Is there any reason why when I set the IF from the second CPU the kernel crashes?
(If I set the IF from CPU0 the kernel will not crash.)

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

When you *send* a function to **another** CPU using `smp_call_function_single` it will be executed by an IPI handler, re-enabling all interrupts inside an interrupt handler isn't something that you want to do. In particular, the documentation of the function that executes your function [explicitly states that all IRQs must be disabled](https://elixir.bootlin.com/linux/latest/source/kernel/smp.c#L188).

When the CPU is the same, your function is simply executed, without sending an IPI, and so `generic_smp_call_function_single_interrupt` and interrupt handlers restrictions don't apply.

Comment: So if I want to hlt other cpus without cpu0, how should I do it with interrupts disabled? sending a NMI while the other cpus inside interrupt handler is still bad. I should wake them up somehow to prevent a lock. Thanks

Comment: I don't understand what you mean. What are you trying to do and why?

Comment: I want to execute some code from one core, while other cores are halted, because I don&amp;#39;t want that any other cores will change or access memory until the 1st core finishes its job. I don't want to disable interrupts in that time

Comment: Of course the best solution would be to use proper locking to properly protect only the memory that you care about. Anyway you could probably spawn N-1 kthreads and use them to halt other CPUs. But I don't like this solution much. What if some interrupts wake them up?

Comment: Thank you for your help.